# Data driven styling using multiple filters in mapbox gl js

Tags: filter, maps, gis, mapbox-gl-js

Common approach of data-driven style using filters is:

`"filter": ["==", "Label Type", "CurbRamp"] // Using one data value/property`

How do I incorporate multiple filters; so incorporating an 'AND' condition using multiple data properties, something like:

```
        // "filter": {
        //     ["==", "Severity", "2.0"],
        //     ["==", "Label Type", "Problem"]
        // }
```

I haven't been able to find any examples on the internet.

Answer (score 14):

You can use an `all` expression:

```
["all", <filter-0>, <filter-1>, <filter-n>]
```

There's also `any` and `none` for combining filters.

Check the documentation here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#all

Comment: Link points to deprecated syntax. New link: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#all

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the link in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

The `all` keyword does this.

In your specific case it would be:

```
"filter": ["all",
    ["==", "Severity", "2.0"],
    ["==", "Label Type", "Problem"]
 ]
```